# Pytorch tensor from loss function won't change data type after casting, which causes a bug

Tags: pytorch

I am using the MSE loss function from pytorch nn module to calculate a loss during training as so:

```
        loss = criterion(prediction, truth)
        loss = loss.to(torch.double)

        optimizer.zero_grad()               
        loss.backward()                      
        optimizer.step()
```

but for some reason I keep getting the error:

```
---> 54             loss.backward()                      
     55             optimizer.step()                    
     56 
    RuntimeError: expected dtype Double but got dtype Long (validate_dtype at /Users/distiller/project/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1587428061935/work/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorIterator.cpp:143)
```

Even though I cast my loss to a double, it still won't work.

For further investigation purposes, when running it in a notebook the following occurs, which may contribute to the problem

```
print(loss)
--> tensor(841645.2747, dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)

l1 = loss.to(torch.double)
print(l1)
--> tensor(841645.2747, dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)

l2 = loss.double()
print(l2)
--> tensor(841645.2747, dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. The input tensors into the loss function were not doubles, thus creating the problem above.

I simply converted prediction and truth to type double and problem solved.

Comment: Yep, integer types don't support gradient computation.